# Search text in JSON Object (Firebase)

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

```
{
"3d7e0037-28b90529e35b":{
"content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis111111 aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
"date":1533572483706
},
"9b135f7-05d34d6a8d8b":{
"content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis222222 aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
"date":1533559442633
},
"b91c71-be1e-8b87a2a57344":{
"content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis222222 aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
"date":1533571768913
},
"f07726-ad27-e1f26b4dacd9":{
"content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis333333 aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
"date":1533567800575
}
}
```

From the above JSON I want to search a string which is in "content" and get total occurrence of it in the whole JSON. For example in this I want to search 'Duis222222' which should return 2.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/6634591), [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Consider using `Object.keys(JSON)` and using the array method `filter`

Comment: How can it return 2 when there is only 1 match

Comment: @brk check now. Updated JSON.

Comment: @evolutionxbox How? Can you please show

Comment: If you search how to use `Object.keys` and `filter` you can do it all on your own! I believe in you.

Comment: @evolutionxbox But in Object.keys I would get only the key. I need to search inside value.

Comment: Maybe use values? `Object.values(obj).map(x => x.content).filter(x => x.contains('Duis222222')).length` --- I can't post an answer, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the keys of the object and then use `reduce` method. In the callback function check if the `content` contains the specific string using `indexOf`. If it is so then add 1

```js
let obj = {
  "3d7e0037-28b90529e35b": {
    "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis111111 aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
    "date": 1533572483706
  },
  "9b135f7-05d34d6a8d8b": {
    "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis222222 aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
    "date": 1533559442633
  },
  "b91c71-be1e-8b87a2a57344": {
    "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis222222 aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
    "date": 1533571768913
  },
  "f07726-ad27-e1f26b4dacd9": {
    "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis333333 aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
    "date": 1533567800575
  }
}
let strToFind = 'Duis222222';
let getAllValues = Object.keys(obj);
let getCount = getAllValues.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
//here obj will the main object & curr will be each element from array of
//keys which we got from Object.keys
  if (obj[curr].content.indexOf(strToFind) !== -1) {
    acc += 1
  }
  return acc;


}, 0);
console.log(getCount)
```

Answer (score 1):

After getting the **keys** You can use the **`filter`** on it.

```js
var jsonObj = {
"3d7e0037-28b90529e35b":{
"content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis111111 aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
"date":1533572483706
},
"9b135f7-05d34d6a8d8b":{
"content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis222222 aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
"date":1533559442633
},
"b91c71-be1e-8b87a2a57344":{
"content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis222222 aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
"date":1533571768913
},
"f07726-ad27-e1f26b4dacd9":{
"content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis333333 aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
"date":1533567800575
}
}

var Count = Object.keys(jsonObj).filter(keys => 
jsonObj[keys].content.includes("Duis222222")).length;
console.log(Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching through the entire JSON tree returned by the Real Time Database may be particularly inefficient and costly in case the number of elements increase in your database. As a matter of facts, each time, you are going to download the entire JSON tree and execute the "search" code on the client.

If you know that your database volume will increase, I suggest you use the Full Text Search solution that you will find in the list of official Cloud Functions templates, [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fulltext-search).  It shows "how to enable full text search on Firebase database elements by using an Algolia hosted search service".

Of course, in case your JSON objects are going to be limited to a small number of (date, content) pairs, then the solutions proposed in the other answers can be used without the drawbacks mentioned above.